# How to get params from the url with aurelia

Tags: aurelia

For example: http://localhost:3000/#/report/123456

How do I get the "123456" part from the url with Aurelia?

Hope you can help me, couldn't find anything useful in the docs.

Answer (score 13):

you can get the submitted params in the activate method of the router (in your viewmodel)

```
activate(params) {
   return this.http.fetch('contacts/' + params.id)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(contact => this.contact = contact);
}
```

found in a nice blogpost here: http://www.elanderson.net/2015/10/aurelia-routing-with-a-parameter/

Comment: I think you might be missing out adding a route for this `{ route: ['report/:id'], moduleId: './report', title: 'Report', name: 'report' },`

Comment: Here is the relevant docs link that talks about params: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/article/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: @JohnManko: that link no longer works, it is now http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

Answer (score 6):

You have to have a route defined for it:

```
{ 
    route: ['report/:id'], 
    moduleId: './report', 
    title: 'Report', 
    name: 'report' 
}
```

Then in your view model, you can get the `id` from the `params` object:

```
activate(params) {  
    console.log(params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the router in the constructor via Dependency Injection and you can use it's values:

```js
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@autoinject()
export class SomeClass {
  
  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  attached() {
    console.log(this.router.currentInstruction.params.myParam);
  }
}
```

The query string params are also available:
e.g.: http://localhost:3000/#/report?id=123456

```js
this.router.currentInstruction.queryParams.id  // "123456"
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Mike's answer (unfortunately I don't have enough credits yet to comment): In case you want your parameter to be optional, you can just add a question mark after the parameter:

```
{ 
    route: ['report/:id?'], 
    moduleId: './report', 
    title: 'Report', 
    name: 'report' 
}
```

Answer (score -8):

```
var str = "http://localhost:3000/#/report/123456";
var res = str.split("/");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[5];
```

Comment: That is not what I mean, the "123456" is a variable and will always be different. I need to know how I can put that into a variable/console log it.